# Incompatibility of Latest version of Anaconda with Python and other libraries

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

I used to use Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) along with Python 3.6.0 and have written several codes and all of them worked fine. I also used Jupyter (Notebook Server 5.0.0) and Spyder too. They all work and my codes were able to run correctly. After recent updates on Anaconda, Spyder and Python all my recent Python codes (those worked before the updates) are not working.

Any Suggestions?

Could you please let me know how I can go back to Anaconda 4.3.1 with Python 3.6.0?

Thank you in advance for an early reply.
Best Regards

I uninstalled and did fresh installation of Anaconda a few times but no 
changed with same errors.

**Please see below for the error messages:**

(TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Software\AnacondaDistribution\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    131     try:
--> 132         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    133     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Software\AnacondaDistribution\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4049                 # must be acceptable as PathCollection facecolors
-> 4050                 colors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c)
   4051             except ValueError: )

matplotlib should plot the figure without any issues.

Comment: What probably happend is that your update updated several versions of the libraries you use and now your code is not compatible to those new versions any more. One cannot know how you need to change your code such that it will work again without seeing the code.

Comment: Open source packages are constantly changing, so you should always pin your code dependencies to specific versions, instead of trying to make things work with the latest versions of everything. My advice is for you to create a new conda environment with your old dependencies and run your code on that env instead of your current one.